# Management of Tags not possible

Tags: tags

Every time when i try to manage the existing tags  i get into a loading loop without any end! No Tag is listed, no modification is possible)[image: loading loop]

Installation: wp 5.x multisite but civicrm is active only on first site right now

what i tried:
 - reinstall complete remove and migrate to external database -> no success
 - reinstall -> no success
 - upgrade to version 5.12.beta1 -> no success ..
used IE Edge, IE11, Firefox (current) for testing already

Anyone have any idea ? without tagging this makes no sence for me ..

Harald

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. This is not a mater of CiviCRM configuration per se; the AJAX in the form is failing to load the tags. If you are familiar with using the console in your browser's developer tools, you should be able to find the specific JavaScript error.

Comment: choster's answer is correct.  I would test with a default WP theme (e.g. twentynineteen) to see if your theme's JavaScript is causing a conflict.  If you don't have experience finding these issues with the browser developer tools, come ask in https://chat.civicrm.org and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers!
It´s true i use Accelerate Pro a paid theme, but normally without any impact right now ..
When i access the Firefox Development Console i got the following error only:

Content Security Policy: Die Einstellungen der Seite haben das Laden einer Ressource auf blob:https://<domainname>/96fdf66b-468b-4764-b70b-ddd44840a6dd blockiert ("default-src").
Sadly not knowing what this means ...

Comment: btw. I use the standard ADMIN Theme, and we are speaking about TAG-Management inside the wp backend! not the frontend which relays on a different theme!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem with the Manage Tags interface that was caused by a 'created_date' field in the tags table having a value of zero. Providing a valid date in the field solved the problem.